# Is there a QGIS fingerprint module?

Tags: qgis, qfield

We are using QField for the front end in data capturing. Currently we are doing a census survey and need to capture fingerprint data, is there a module or plugin available in QGIS and how do we implement this.

Comment: Can you specify if you are looking for a module in QGIS or QField. I wouldn't be aware of anything like this but it could certainly be added on either side if you contact the developers.

Comment: Specifically QField, or QGIS becuase QGIS will run on a Windows Tablet on a Trimble Yuma Tablet which is windows based. Currently we have have 6 Android driven tablets where we use Qfield.

Comment: I know for sure that there is nothing available for QField yet, but [it is probably not impossible to change that](http://www.qfield.org/docs/development/index.html#external-measurement-devices). I guess it's the same for QGIS (difference: I'm only 85% sure about the current state).